# Mean Stack - Angular passing parameters from controller to $resource object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, get, mean-stack, angular-resource

I have posted a couple of times thinking that my problem was in the passing of parameters to the Express server.  I have since shown the problem to be on the Angular side.  When I hardcoded the id in the flConstruct.js function the query worked as expected.   It looks like the id is not being passed from the flCachedConstructs function to the “get” in the flConstruct.  As you can see I use the console log to print out the id in a number of locations and the proper id is printed out.  For some reason the parameter is not being associated with the get in flConstruct.  Maybe my spacing or syntax is not quite right. Any insight that you can provide would be appreciated.

```
// flConstructDetailCtrl.js
angular.module('app').controller('flConstructDetailCtrl', function($scope, flCachedConstructs, $stateParams, $state, flConstructDataService, flQuestionQueryParameterService){

console.log('Just inside the flConstructDetailCtr');
console.log('flConstructDetailCtr - before promise - $stateParams.id ' + $stateParams.id);


    flCachedConstructs.queryID($stateParams.id)
    .then(function(data) {
        // work with data here
        console.log("flConstructDetailCtr - Get Success " + data);
        console.log("flConstructDetailCtr - Get Success Question description " + data.description);
        console.log("flConstructDetailCtr - Get Success Question id " + data._id);
        flConstructDataService.setInitialized(true);

        flConstructDataService.setNewConstructId(data._id);
        flConstructDataService.setNewTitle(data.title);
        flConstructDataService.setNewDescription(data.description);
        $state.go("constructUpdate");
    });


//flCachedConstructs.js

angular.module('app').factory('flCachedConstructs', function(flConstruct,$http, $q, $state, $timeout) {
var constructList = null;  // temporarily set to null for testing purposes

return {
    queryID: function(id) {
        console.log("flCachedConstruct - queryID function by ID - start");
        console.log("flCachedConstruct - queryID function by ID - parameter = constructId " + id);
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        flConstruct.get(id, function(data) {
            if (data) {
                deferred.resolve(data);
                console.log("flCachedConstruct - queryID function by ID - resolved Data = " + data);
                console.log("flCachedConstruct - queryID function by ID - resolved Data data.description " + data.description);
                console.log("flCachedConstruct - queryID function by ID - resolved Data data._id " + data._id);
            }
            else {
                deferred.reject("Error getting Construct");
                console.log("flCachedConstruct - queryID function by ID - rejected Data");
            }
        });
        console.log("flCachedConstruct - queryID function by ID - return Promise data");
        return deferred.promise;
    },

}
})


//flConstruct.js

angular.module('app').factory('flConstruct',function($resource){
var ConstructResource = $resource('/api/constructs/:id', {id: '@id'}, {
    get: { method: 'GET', url: '/api/constructs/byId', params: {id: '@id'}},
//get: { method: 'GET', url: '/api/constructs/byId', params: {id: '570ab7c086ccc2d81ac18fa6'}},  (By hard coding the query worked as expected)

    query: { method: 'GET' , url: '/api/constructs', isArray: true },
    create: { method: 'POST'},
    update: { method: 'PUT' },
    delete: { method: 'DELETE', params: {id: '@id'}}
});

return ConstructResource;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake.  The call to the get that is made in the flCachedConstruct.js did not properly define the parameter to be passed.   I needed to include the parameter name, "id" as well as the parameter value, constructID.  The "id" in this function call matches what I called the parameter in flConstruct.js.

flConstruct.get({id: constructId }, function(data) {